# Adding a dynamic attribute to products

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, dynamic

I wish to add a dynamic attribute to products. I am looking to add an attribute "Calorie" associated with food products and wish to add them in bundled products much in the same way as their price add up.For eg, if I have a platter of fruits and fruit A is 40 calories and food B is 30 calories. When I keep both of them in my platter the total calorie of the platter should be 70, i.e. the sum of both individual products. Is there a way to add a dynamic attribute or is there any other way to approach this ?

Comment: Via setup script  or on the fly?

Comment: I would  like to add on the fly.

Comment: This should work:
You create a regular custom attribute. Then create simple products for each item in the product packs and add the individual calorie value into your custom attribute on these products.

Then create a group or bundle product and add the simple products to it. Now in the product page template you could get the attribute value for each simple product in the bundle/group, add them together and output them.

Comment: I am new to magento,can you tell me exact file and location and code I need to add. Thanks